# Scraping webdata returning no result

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data (59,805) from the mentioned URL. And I am using BeautifulSoup and requests package of Python.

Below is the code I am trying, however its giving me no result. Down below is the HTML code, where from I am trying to extract. The result should be 'Confirmed', 59,805

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

case_type = []
count = []

url = requests.get('https://www.covid19india.org/')
soup = bs(url.content,'html.parser')

for a in soup.findAll('div',  attrs={'class':'level-item is-cherry fadeInUp'}):
    b = a.find('h1')
    c = a.find('h5')
    case_type.append(c.text)
    count.append(b.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Case Type':case_type, 'Count':count})
print(df)
```

HTML code snippet from the said page

```
 <div class="Level">
      <div class="level-item is-cherry fadeInUp" style="animation-delay: 1s;">
        <h5>Confirmed</h5>
        <h4>[+115]</h4>
        <h1>59,805 </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="level-item is-blue fadeInUp" style="animation-delay: 1.1s;">
        <h5 class="heading">Active</h5>
        <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
        <h1 class="title has-text-info">39,914</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="level-item is-green fadeInUp" style="animation-delay: 1.2s;">
        <h5 class="heading">Recovered</h5>
        <h4>[+14]</h4>
        <h1 class="title has-text-success">17,901 </h1>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has been created in React so the content you're pulling in via requests won't include all of the site content as this is loaded dynamically

If you look at the network requests the site makes when it loads you'll see that the information is coming from:

```
https://api.covid19india.org/data.json
```

So you could (assuming you don't affect the site performance / have permission) do:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json')
j = r.json()
confirmed = j['statewise'][0]['confirmed']
print(confirmed)
```

Comment: Thanks.. But what if the site has been created in React and the response does not come through json (unlike */data.json this case)..how to pull the data, in that case

Comment: Do you have an example of the other data you're looking for? There are multiple calls being made to different endpoints (eg https://api.covid19india.org/updatelog/log.json)